# EF 5.0 Foreign Key Not Updating

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, foreign-key-relationship

I know there are some other questions regarding this-- but I was unable to get them to solve my problem.

I have the following classes:

```
public class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        Products = new List<Product>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}{1}", Id, Name);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}{1}", Id, Name);
    }
}
```

I've got some code which attempts to update both a product and it's category:

```
        using (var ctx = GetCtx())
        {
            var beverages = new Category {Id = 1 };

            var milk = new Product { Name = "MILK", Id = 4, Category = new Category { Id = 1} };       
            ctx.Entry(milk).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
```

this results in the following sql statement:

```
update [dbo].[Products]
set [Name] = @0, [Price] = @1
where ([Id] = @2)

@0: MILK
@1: 0
@2: 4
```

I can't figure out how to make sure that the Category for the particular product is updated. I thought about adding a property to Product for Category_Id but this results in an additional column being generated in my database.

EDIT:
I think I figured this out-- after watching Julia Lerman's series on EF (Pluralsight)-- the way to set up this class is like this:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

}
```

This results in only one foreign key column in the Products table. The Category of the Product gets updated when updating the CategoryId property.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do two jobs, so do them in two operations...

```
var cat = ctx.Categories.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.Id == 1);
if(cat == null){
    cat = new Category{Id=1};
    ctx.Categies.Add(cat);
}
cat.Products.Add(new Product{Name="Milk", Id=4};
try{
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}catch(Exception ex){
    return RedirectToResponse("someone else got in first with that category Id");
}
```